# Shifted Catalan Recurrence

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a recurrence for a seqence $t_n$ which is given n points on a circle, the number of ways to pair any number of them by noncrossing chords and color the remaining with 2 colors.  I have $t_n = \sum_{k \geq 0} {n \choose 2k}2^{n-2k}C_k$ where $C_k$ is the $k$th Catalan number.  It seems to follow a Catalan sequence shifted by 1: ($1,2,5,14,42,...$). I can't seem to find a way to obtain this recurrence though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not hard to see that $$\binom{n}{2k}2^{n-2k}C_k$$ is the number of words $x$ of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $|x|_a=|x|_b=k$, and the substring of $x$ consisting of the $a$s and $b$s is a [Dyck word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) of length $2k$: there are $\binom{n}{2k}$ ways to choose $2k$ positions for the Dyck substring, $C_k$ possible Dyck substrings of length $2k$, and $2^{n-2k}$ ways to assign symbols $c$ or $d$ to the remaining $n-2k$ positions of $x$. Summing over $k$, we get the number of words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that if we delete all $c$s and $d$s, what’s left is a Dyck word.

I will construct a bijection between such words and the set of rooted binary trees with $n+1$ vertices. Since it’s well-known that there are $C_{n+1}$ such trees, this will establish that

$$\binom{n}{2k}2^{n-2k}C_k=C_{n+1}\;.$$

My trees grow down from the root. Let $w$ be such a word of length $n$. Each letter of $w$ will correspond to one of the $n$ edges of a binary tree on $n+1$ vertices:

- each $a$ represents an edge to a left daughter that has a sister;
- each $b$ represents an edge to a right daughter that has a sister;
- each $c$ represents an edge to a left daughter that has no sister; and
- each $d$ represents an edge to a right daughter that has no sister.

The substring obtained by deleting the $c$s and $d$s is effectively a balanced string of parentheses, with $a$ as left and $b$ as right parentheses, so each $a$ can be matched uniquely with a corresponding $b$; a matched pair correspond to the left and right daughters of some vertex of the tree.

To build the tree from the string, start with the root. If the first letter is $a$, give the root left and right daughters, and finding the matching $b$; the substring between the $a$ and $b$ will generate the subtree having the root’s left daughter as its root, and the substring after the $b$ will generate the subtree having the root’s right daughter as its root. If the first letter is a $c$, give the root a left daughter; the remainder of the word will generate the subtree having that left daughter as root. And if the first letter is a $d$, give the root a right daughter; the remainder of the word will generate the subtree having that right daughter as root. Apply this algorithm recursively.

> **Example.** Suppose that $w=dacdabdbc$; the resulting tree is shown below.
>
> ```
>                                            o   
>                                             \d  
>                                              o  
>                                            a/ \b  
>                                            /   \  
>                                           o     o  
>                                         c/    c/  
>                                         o     o  
>                                          \d  
>                                           o  
>                                         a/ \b  
>                                         o   o  
>                                              \d  
>                                               o
> ```

The inverse algorithm to convert a binary tree to a corresponding word should be pretty clear.